# Watchkit app and extension appear red

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, watchkit

I was integrating watch kit for my app and I messed it up so I deleted the watchkit app and extension from my project and then I created a new watchkit app and extension target but now they appear red. The problem is for some reason I am unable to edit the path and I can not find the file anywhere on my computer. Please help![image]

Comment: Are you able to build the new targets?

Comment: Yeah it lets me build and everything